# Importing domain classes from GORM-standalone module into Grails

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I have 2 pieces of my puzzle:

1) a no-Grails project named `core-module` with standalone GORM:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-mongodb:6.0.4.RELEASE'
  compile 'org.grails:grails-validation:3.2.3'
}
```

and domain classes like:

```
import grails.gorm.annotation.Entity

@Entity
class Module {
  String id
  String tags
 }
```

the GORM-ing is initialized by

```
Map config = new Yaml().load this.class.getResource( '/application.yml' ).text
new MongoDatastore( config, Module, UserAccount )
```

and the domain classes are working as they would in a Grails app.

2) a `Grails 3.2.3` app:

```
dependencies {
  // default grails dependencies

  compile project( ':core-module' )
  compile 'org.grails.plugins:mongodb:6.0.4'
  compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1'
  // etc
}
```

the GORM is initialized so:

```
def config = config.grails.mongodb
log.info "using $config"
new MongoDatastore( config, Module, UserAccount )
```

and it prints out this into the log file:

> g.app.init.com.mozaiq.Application - using [host:localhost, port:27017, databaseName:theDB, username:theUN, pooled:true, mongoOptions:[connectionsPerHost:100, autoConnectRetry:true, connectTimeout:3000]]

The problem is, that the property `grailsApplication.domainClasses` is empty, and even though the `Module.collection` is not-null, the `Module.count()` return `0` despite the collection being not empty.

Also in my mongo-client I see that upon app start a new database `test` is created with an empty collection, named by one of my domain classes. If I insert some documents into it, the `.count()` returns `0` and the CRUD list remains empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grails only scans packages in the application by default for performance reasons. Override `limitScanningToApplication()` to return `false` in your `Application` class and define the packages you wish to scan by overriding `packageNames()` in your `Application` class.

Grails will then automatically discover the Mongo GORM classes

Comment: is it possible to scan all domain classes in some package also in non-Grails app?

Comment: Also I noticed, that the `respond` method in a controller returns an empty domain instance, like `def show( Module module ){ respond module }` shows an empty page

Comment: We are adding scanning for GORM 6.1, in the meantime you can write your own scanning using code similar to this https://github.com/grails/gorm-hibernate5/blob/6.0.x/grails-plugin/src/main/groovy/grails/test/hibernate/HibernateSpec.groovy#L48

Comment: how can I achieve the same behaviour in Mirconaut?