# How to import domain classes from jar into a Micronaut project?

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, grails-orm, micronaut

I have a Micronaut project configured to use GORM and Groovy (1). This project contains lots of domain classes that are working perfectly, persisting data in a MySQL database as expected.

Now I wish to make this domain classes common to another Micronaut project (2).

I tried building a JAR file containing only the domain package and including it in the project (2) through `build.gradle`. The classes are compiled and made accessible in code, and I'm able to call GORM methods like `findBy`, `createCriteria`, etc. Is also good to mention that all project 2's domain classes are annotated with `@Entity`.

But, when I run the project (using IntelliJ idea) and hit some of this code I get:

```
Either class [com.project2.domain.Foo] is not a 
domain class or GORM has not been initialized correctly or has already 
been shutdown. Ensure GORM is loaded and configured correctly before 
calling any methods on a GORM entity.
```

I know that GORM is well configured and initialized because I created a "local" domain class inside project 2 and things worked fine.

Before asking this question I saw this one and maybe it can bring some inspiration: [Importing domain classes from GORM-standalone module into Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41143475/importing-domain-classes-from-gorm-standalone-module-into-grails)

EDIT 1: Current `build.gradle` dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile "io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-kafka"
    compile "io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-hibernate-validator"

    compile("io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-hibernate-gorm") {
        exclude group: 'org.grails', module: 'grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate5'
    }
    compile "org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate5:6.1.9.RELEASE"

    compile "io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client"
    compile "io.micronaut:micronaut-http-server-netty"
    compile "io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime-groovy"
    compile "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation"
    compileOnly "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    runtime "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"

    runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"

    runtime "mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.6"

    testCompile "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"

    testCompile("org.spockframework:spock-core") {
        exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy", module: "groovy-all"
    }

    compile files('src/main/resources/libs/my-domain-lib.jar')
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using a similar setup.

I have a core-lib with GORM-standalone, and couple of (Vert.x) verticles and Grails apps using those via gradle's `compile project()` or `compile dep:from-artifactory:0.1-SNAPSHOT` directives.

In order to make it possible I needed to:

1) Make sure that each domain class is annotated with `grails.gorm.annotation.Entity`

2) Tweak Grails' `Application.groovy` like that:

```
class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration {

  @Override
  protected boolean limitScanningToApplication() {
    false
  }

  @Override
  Collection<String> packageNames() {
    super.packageNames() + 'your.domainclass.package'
  }

}
```

3) For no-Grails projects I needed to find and initialize the domain classes myself, and for each DB it can be different (mine is for `Mongo-GORM`)

```
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider compProvider = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider( false )
compProvider.addIncludeFilter new AnnotationTypeFilter( Entity )
def domainClasses = compProvider.findCandidateComponents( 'io.my.domain' ).collect{ BeanDefinition bd -> Class.forName bd.beanClassName }
new MongoDatastore( config, *domainClasses )
```

Comment: Number 3 is exactly what I want. How exactly did you managed to accomplish that? I also work a lot with Grails, but Micronaut works differently and I couldn't find a way to scan for classes outside Application.groovy package.

Comment: That is it. Just changed MongoDatastore for HibernateDatastore (and the package name, of course) and it worked like a charm. Thanks!