# Is it possible to use ORM together with Vert.x?

Tags: java, asynchronous, orm, vert.x

As I understand there is an async JDBC driver that is Vert.x compatible:
https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-jdbc-client/java/

But at the same time I haven't found any information about usage of Java ORMs together with Vert.x.

Can someone shed some light on that?

Comment: If you find a reactive ORM, sure. Not sure one exists. ORMs are heavy, cache based and transactional. In many ways the opposite of everything Vert.X is. Strongly consider whether you need an ORM.

Comment: I'm using GORM like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53621770/how-to-import-domain-classes-from-jar-into-a-micronaut-project/53629578#53629578

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Hibernate Reactive](https://hibernate.org/reactive/documentation/1.0/reference/html_single/)

> Hibernate Reactive is a reactive API for Hibernate ORM, supporting non-blocking database drivers and a reactive style of interaction with the database.

> Out of the box, the Vert.x clients for PostgreSQL, MySQL, and DB2 are supported, though the architecture is not limited to these drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any full-featured Java ORM that has non blocking APIs.

This is why if you want to use an ORM in a Vert.x application, you should use `executeBlocking` to wrap the ORM calls or put your persistence code in a worker verticle.

There's an [example](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/spring-examples/spring-worker-example) for this scenario in the `vertx-examples` repository.

Alternatively, you could a tool like [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/), an active community member has developed a [neat integration](https://github.com/jklingsporn/vertx-jooq).

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a framework focused on fast query processing and an ORM that annihilates performance (and often makes deadlocks and other issues that are hard to be fixed)