# Using GORM in Micronaut in Grails manner

Tags: grails, groovy, transactions, grails-orm, micronaut

Is it possible to use GORM in Micronaut without  `Service`s?

I want to be able to write something very straight-forward:

```
@Controller( '/my' )
class MyController {

  @Get( uri='/bundle' )
  @Transactional( readOnly = true )
  Map bundle() {
    [ domainAList:DomainA.list(), domainBList:DomainB.list() ]
  }

}
```

Upon calling the action throws

> failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.domain.DomainA.links, could not initialize proxy - no Session

where `links` is a `hasMany` in the class `DomainA`.

The same exception occurs also, if I replace `@Transactional` with `DomainA.withTransaction{...}`, because the reference resolution occurs outside of the action and is not covered by any OSIV TX-filter.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to use GORM in Micronaut without  Services?

Yes.  GORM does not require services.

**EDIT**

The issue isn't really service related as much as it is the case that Hibernate requires a session to be started.  Services can manage that for you, but are not required.

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/gormnoservice.  The code below is a bad idea, but addresses the question as asked.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/gormnoservice/blob/master/src/main/groovy/gormnoservice/Person.groovy

```
package gormnoservice

import grails.gorm.annotation.Entity

@Entity
class Person {
    String name
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/gormnoservice/blob/4ee6d7786677f769c3a6b70eb939750271922cb5/src/main/groovy/gormnoservice/MyController.groovy

```
package gormnoservice

import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Post
import io.micronaut.http.HttpStatus


@Controller("/my")
class MyController {

    @Post('/{name}')
    Person create(String name) {
        Person p
        Person.withNewSession {
           p = new Person(name:name).save()
        }
        p
    }

    @Get('/')
    Map list() {
        List people
        Person.withNewSession {
            people = Person.list()
        }
        [people: people]
    }
}
```

It works:

```
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/my/Jake
{"name":"Jake","id":1}
$ 
$ 
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/my/Zack
{"name":"Zack","id":2}
$ 
$ 
$ curl http://localhost:8080/my
{"people":[{"name":"Jake","id":1},{"name":"Zack","id":2}]}
```

Comment: slightly offtopic, but how can I run micronaut with domain classes from external GORM-standalone project as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41143475/importing-domain-classes-from-gorm-standalone-module-into-grails ? now I'm using this trick https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53621770/how-to-import-domain-classes-from-jar-into-a-micronaut-project/53629578#53629578 to achieve this. Can I bind the dataSource with domain classes automatically?

Comment: There isn't really anything special about using domain classes from an external standalone project.  As long as that gorm entity project is compiled with the correct dependencies, another project can simply express a dependency on the gorm entity project and then the entities are available in that project.

Comment: Yes that works. My question was rather about automatic initialization of those external domain classes in Micronaut app. Now I'm using smth like `new HibernateDatastore( config, DomainA, DomainB, ... )` explicitely

Comment: Why is it that you are creating the `HibernateDatestore` explicitly?

Comment: You haven't provided enough info to know what the issue is and if you could provide a simple pair of projects which demonstrate the issue you are having, that would be helpful.  My first guess is that your entities are not in a sub-package of whatever package your `Application` class is in and if that is the case, you will have to configure the packages to scan via the `ApplicationContextBuilder`.

Comment: Separate from all of that, the answer to the question you asked in the original post is "Yes".

Comment: Yes, my entities are outside of the Application's package. Can you elaborate on `scan via the ApplicationContextBuilder`? Can I use there something like `limitScanningToApplication()` and `packageNames()` like for Grails' `Application` class?

Answer (score -3):

I think for your problem to be solve, lazy initialization should be avoided. Suggest to map your db objects to a DTO before output it to JSON.

GORM can be used in Micronaut.

I've written an article on it.

https://medium.com/@S1lv3rd3m0n/micronaut-groovy-with-gorm-3a2d0b12e86b

Comment: Lazy initialization isn't really the issue.  Using Hibernate without an open session is the issue.  Even if there were no relationships to another entity and everything was eagerly fetched, the same issue exists.